# Find $E$ : $\| x \|_1 \le E \| x \|_2 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

$$\frac{\| x \|_1}{\| x \|_2} \le E$$

$$\frac{\| x \|_1}{\| x \|_2} \le \frac{n\| x \|_{\infty}}{\| x \|_2}$$

Considering :

$$\frac{\| x \|_{\infty}}{\| x \|_2} \le 1$$

Because:

$$\| x \|_{\infty} \le \cdots \le \| x \|_3 \le \| x \|_2 \le \| x \|_1  $$

So:

$$ \frac{n\| x \|_{\infty}}{\| x \|_2} \le n$$

$$E=n$$

Is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is! But I guess, the question is not properly stated. For instance, the inequality still holds even if I say, something like $E=n^2$? Think about it!

Comment: It depends how you define $E$. If you define $E:=\inf\{|y|\in\Bbb R:\|x\|_1\le \|x\|_2\quad\forall x\in\Bbb R\}$ then your answer is not enough. But of course is true that if you want some constant $K$ such that $\|x\|_1\le K\|x\|_2,\forall x\in\Bbb R$ then $K=n$ holds.

Comment: Think about how you could employ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$. Then
$$\|x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n 1\cdot |x_i|\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}=\sqrt{n}\>\|x\|_2$$
with equality sign iff all $|x_i|$ are equal. The "optimal" value for $E$ therefore is $\sqrt{n}$.